# Keeping track of running total whilst subtracting values at certain timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, time-series

I have a DataFrame like so:

```py
    time_start            pred      time_end_floor          xyz
0   2022-05-06 12:00:00    26              NaT              NaN 
1   2022-05-06 13:00:00    16              NaT              NaN
2   2022-05-06 14:00:00    10        2022-05-06 14:00:00    4.0
3   2022-05-06 15:00:00    8         2022-05-06 15:00:00    9.0
4   2022-05-06 16:00:00    11        2022-05-06 16:00:00    15.0
```

I need to calculate a running total but whilst also subtracting values based on when a value in `time_end_floor` occurs.

EG)
The running total goes like 26+16+10 until 14:00:00 and then I need to subtract the value from column `xyz` 4. So the value I want in another column at 14:00:00 is 48 as it is (26+16+10) - 4. So 48 goes into the other column at 14:00:00.

Then the next row adds on 8 to 48 to equal 56 but at the same time subtracts 9 so in the other column at 15:00:00 it should show 47 and so on.

At the end of the DataFrame I should be back to 0 as the last entry. Ideally want this as quick as possible as I know it could be done using `apply()` but could cause severe overhead.

Comment: `df["cred"].cumsum() - df["xyz"].cumsum()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact expected output is unclear (do you need a shift?), but you can use:

```
df['sum'] = df['pred'].cumsum().sub(df['xyz'].fillna(0, downcast='infer').cumsum())
```

unless you want 26+16+10 for all the NaN values? Here as sum2

```
s = df['pred'].cumsum()
df['sum2'] = s.sub(df['xyz'].cumsum()).fillna(s.mask(df['xyz'].isna()).bfill(), downcast='infer')
```

output:

```
            time_start  pred       time_end_floor   xyz  sum  sum2
0  2022-05-06 12:00:00    26                  NaT   NaN   26    52
1  2022-05-06 13:00:00    16                  NaT   NaN   42    52
2  2022-05-06 14:00:00    10  2022-05-06 14:00:00   4.0   48    48
3  2022-05-06 15:00:00     8  2022-05-06 15:00:00   9.0   47    47
4  2022-05-06 16:00:00    11  2022-05-06 16:00:00  15.0   43    43
```